# Querying an ICollection in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

ASP NET MVC5 web application, E.F.6, Visual Studio 2015

CategoryTrans model class is a virtual ICollection in Category model class.

Category model class is a virtual property in Product model class.

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

 public partial class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryTrans> CategoryTrans { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryTrans
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int language_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("category_id")]
    public virtual Category categoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("language_id")]
    public virtual ISO_Languages languageId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

CategoryTrans has a composite PK made by Category and ISO_languages FK. When querying the tables and filling the productviewmodel with products and related category translations I get ALL category's translation (one 'category_id' together with all 'language_id' in Product.Category.CategoryTrans collection.

**What I need to do is filtering the single translation (CategoryTrans.name) as per user culture input parameter.**

I supposed that could be done by setting a ViewModel property as:

```
public CategoryTrans CategoryTrans
    {
        get
        {
            HttpUtilities HttpHelper = new HttpUtilities();
            string culture = HttpHelper.getShortCulture();
            var CT = Product.Category.CategoryTrans.Select(x => new CategoryTrans
            {
                name = x.name
            })
            .Where(b => b.language_id.Equals(culture)).FirstOrDefault();
            return CT;
        }
```

And, in View:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryTrans.name)
```

But it keeps returning empty values while I can see CategoryTrans ICollection is correctly populated.
Am I trying to do something impossible or is it just a wrong syntax matter?

Comment: Your `language_id` is integer right?

Comment: Did you validate `b.language_id.Equals(culture)` if this condition is working in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by adding a

`[NotMapped]
 public virtual string LocalizedCategoryName { get; set; }`

to Product model Class, in charge for displaying localized category name, and setting two nested foreach loops, returning a new List of fully localized products:

```
private List<Product> _LocalizedProductList = new List<Product>();

public List<Product> LocalizedProductList
    {
        get
        {
            HttpUtilities HttpHelper = new HttpUtilities();
            string culture = HttpHelper.getFullCulture();
            int IsoCode = GenericUtilities.getIsoID(culture, db);
            List<Product> localized = new List<Product>();

            foreach (Product p in _LocalizedProductList)
            {
                foreach (CategoryTrans c in p.Category.CategoryTrans)
                {
                    if (c.language_id.Equals(IsoCode))
                    {
                        Product x = new Product
                        {
                            ID = p.ID,
                            LocalizedCategoryName = c.name,
                            DateCreated = p.DateCreated,
                            DateExpire = p.DateExpire,
                            DateLastModified = p.DateLastModified,
                            Name = p.Name,
                            Description = p.Description,
                            IsApproved = p.IsApproved,
                            IsDeleted = p.IsDeleted,
                            ProductImages = p.ProductImages,
                            User = p.User
                        };
                        localized.Add(x);
                    };
                }
            }
            return localized;
        }

        set { _LocalizedProductList = value; }
    }
```

No idea if it's the best or the only way to do it, but works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to language_id in select. But you can still optimize your query.

```
public CategoryTrans CategoryTrans
{
    get
    {
        HttpUtilities HttpHelper = new HttpUtilities();
        string culture = HttpHelper.getShortCulture();
        var CT = Product.Category.CategoryTrans
        .FirstOrDefault(b => b.languageId.Equals(culture));
        return CT;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like nothing but a different syntax. As a matter of fact I keep on getting same null result.

Comment: Have you set Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true; to load foreign key tables? If set then check whether you are able to fetch data from **CategoryTrans**

Comment: I was referencing wrong item in View: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryTrans.name) while It should be @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.CategoryTrans.name). Now I get a System.NullReferenceException error in both selects.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to fetch CategoryTrans.name filtering on CategoryTrans.language_id.Equals(culture) from populated property List<Product> productList { get; set; } in ViewModel